# Calling a Function in Functions.php from an external PHP script

Tags: functions, include

**Preamble**

*I tried to make sure this question was not asked before. I'm new to using StackExchange so I may have failed in doing so. I don't mind rebukes; thick skin and I learn fast :)*

**THE PROBLEM**

I wrote a function and placed in my theme's functions.php

```
function serverConnect() {

$serverAccess = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$serverAccess) {
    die("Access Denied");
}

return $serverAccess; 
}
```

The idea was to be able to have the ability to log into the DB abstracted to a function so whenever my unconventional theme needed it I could log in and do what needed to be done.

As I built more functions, I felt it would be advantageous to break off some functionality into external php files. This script is called when a form is posted in the admin cp.

In *theme-root/scripts/hypothetical-theme-function.php*:

```
$switch = mysql_select_db( 'differentDB', serverConnent());
```

The problem here is that *hypothetical-theme-function.php* has no access to functions.php to be able to call serverConnect();

I've tried include(/path/to/functions.php), include_once(/path/to/functions.php), require(/path/to/functions.php) and require_once(/path/to/functions.php). The errors I get with the once commands is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function serverConnent() ...
```

The problem I get with include or require is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare serverConnect() ...
```

**THE QUESTION**

How do I call any function in Functions.php from an external php script?

Answer (score 1):

You're much better off with using a (mu-)plugin. Just add a folder named  `mu-plugins` in your `wp-content` directory and place your files there. Then add a plugin header comment to it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Some Name
 * Plugin URI: http://example.com
 * Description: Loads something
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Akamaozu
 * Author URI: http://example.com
 * License: GNU GPL 2 <https://gist.github.com/1365159>
 */
// deny direct file access if WP not loaded
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;

// define your functions here
function foo()
{
    print '<h1>'.__FILE__.' loaded successfully!</h1>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'foo' );
```

Comment: I'm not trying to build a plugin though. I wanted this baked into a theme for a particular reason. I appreciate the help, but I decided very early in I'm not trying to build a plugin so this solution is not a viable one for me.

Comment: @Akamaozu Are you selling it, so it can't reside in a plugin folder? Because else, I'd suggest to rethink it: Plugins add _functionality_ and themes are _for markup and design_. **EDIT**: Is this for an AJAX callback?

Comment: 1. I will be selling it sooner or later. Highly unlikely to be in the form that it is. It's planned to be a SAAS but I'm building this for my own benefit and modelling til the real software engineer starts work. I may release a Wordpress Theme for sale later. Maybe.

2. There will be some AJAX functionality to the final version.

Comment: Ad 2) Is the above ↑ DB stuff for an AJAX call?

Comment: Currently isn't an AJAX call, but it will be when I'm done. 
I skirted the issue by putting `serverConnect()` in an external script, so that the clash doesn't happen. 

Still would love to know how to do this for the sake of learning, but it's not a pressing concern right now. I suspect the problem is `wp-load.php` or `wp-blog-header.php` load up the whole WP environment which calls `functions.php`. Redoing that gives errors, yet the one they call is outside the scope of the external file. 

Might be able to avoid the issue by specifically calling `wp-config.php` and `functions.php` only.

Comment: ...which would be an _ugly_ hack and error prone. Doing DB requests via AJAX the "WP way" isn't that hard. Just take a look at [tag:ajax].

Answer (score 0):

From within your external script try calling `wp-load.php` - example;

```
require( '../your-path-to-your-wp-base-directory/wp-load.php' );
```

See how you fair then...

Comment: I've tried that. 

I've tried `wp-load.php` and `wp-blog-header.php` *(which I believe is the recommended way of calling the WP Environment)*. They work because I used a Wordpress function `print_r (get_all_page_ids());` and it works perfectly.

My problem still persists though :(

Comment: Odd. I ran a test for example sake and created a function named `foo();` in my `functions.php` file with a `$var = bar;` and run `echo foo();` on `external.php` with the above `require` to `wp-load.php` (or '..blog-header.php' if you prefer) and my result was `// bar`. So its working for me on a custom function and its working for you on WP's inbuilt functions. Have you done an `include 'hypothetical-function.php';` within your actual functions.php file?

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could please paste the function snippet from `functions.php` with the `include(/path/to/script.php)` and `external.php` please. 

I've tried many variants and I either get it trying to redeclare my functions.php internal function or it doesn't see it at all. 

Thanks a lot for your help so far, @userabuser. I really appreciate it.